# Mocha subbing results are different based on the file path

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to set up stubbing out of middleware using Sinon in my Node App.
When I run a mocha test and point directly to the test file it stubs out correctly. When I point to all my testing folder and run the tests recursively it does not stub out the middleware and fails.

File Structure:

```
test
  functional
    checklist
      test.spec.js
lib
  middleware
   auth.js (this is what is being stubbed out)
```

**test.spec.js**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const should = chai.should();

// Requirements
const auth = require('../../../lib/middleware/auth')

describe('/checklist/checklistItemLevel',function() {
    let checkTokenStub;
    beforeEach(function(){
        checkTokenStub = sinon.stub(auth,'checkToken').callsFake((req,res,next)=>{
            console.log('Stubbed')
            next()
        });


    })
    afterEach(function(){
        auth.checkToken.restore();
    })
    context('/ POST',function() {
        it('should return hello',function(done){
            chai.request(require('../../../server'))
            .post('/api/v1/checklist/checklistItemLevel')
            .end((err,res)=>{
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.text.should.be.eql('Hello');
                done(err);
            })
        })
    })
})
```

**router.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const controller = require('./controller')
const auth = require('../../../lib/middleware/auth')

router.post('/',auth.checkToken,(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send('Hello');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Mocha Calls**

```
mocha "**/*.spec.js" // <- Doesnt stub out middleware
mocha "test/functional/checklist/*.spec.js" // <- Stubs out successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Mocha is working properly. But the app is being cached by another test case so its running without the stubs